# Can Rogue absorb and utilize powers from multiple mutants simultaneously?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, powers, rogue

It is established that Rogue absorbs and is capable of utilizing powers from any mutant she makes skin to skin contact with, but what happens when Rogue makes contact with multiple mutants? Is she limited to only being able to utilize the most recently touched mutant, or is she able to 'stack' powers?

If she can 'stack' powers, is there any specific instance in the comics where she uses powers from multiple mutants simultaneously?

If she can only keep the power of the most recent mutant touched, is there any specific instance in the comics where this reaction is depicted?

Comment: I'd say this question could use the tag  `rogue`, since we have one, but I also think the maximum amount of tags is 5, so I'll just put that thought here and leave you to decide if you nuke one of the tags you first used or not :)

Comment: Nuked Marvel tag... we know Rogue and X-men are marvel, no need to be too redundant on tags.

Comment: https://comicnewbies.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/rogue-second-coming.jpg - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Second_Coming

Comment: She's done it more times that I can easily count. Certainly a dozen or more.... https://comicnewbies.com/2014/06/09/rogue-takes-down-a-predator-x/

Comment: http://panels-of-interest.tumblr.com/post/135936900963/rogue-vs-nimrod-from-uncanny-x-men-1963-194

Comment: https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/13/131045/4505472-3471929521-tumbl.jpg

Comment: @Valorum make it into an answer.

Comment: @onewho - I really can't be bothered to copy-paste all those pictures into something that looks like an answer. To be frank, it happens so often it's like asking if Professor X has ever complained of having a headache

Comment: FYI - I swapped the `mutant` tag out, and put back the `marvel` tag. Rogue's power can absorb anyone's powers, not just mutants. The `marvel` tag seems more important - some people would want to pull up all questions about Marvel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Valorum notes, Rogue has done this on more than one occasion.

I believe the first time she did it was in *Uncanny X-Men* #194, cover-dated June 1985 (She joined the team in issue #180).

Kitty Pryde's the one who initiates it, as you see:

[image: Kitty uses Rogue's power to communicate]

[image: Rogue becomes a one-man X-men team]

Evidently, the editors guessed that this development would be of interest, featuring her temporary "new look" on the cover:

[image: Cover of *Uncanny X-Men* #194]

As Valorum noted in the comments, she's done it several times since. They haven't always decided that it would modify here appearance; in *Uncanny X-Men* 517 (cover-dated January 2010), her appearance is unchanged, despite drawing powers from characters with such unusual appearances as Rockslide, Anole, and Mercury:

[image: Rogue absorbing multiple powers]

[image: Rogue using multiple powers]